# Why is Time Complexity of Bucket Sort is O(n^2) and not O(log(n) * n^2)?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, data-structures, bucket-sort

```
import math

def insertionSort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[i]:
                arr[j], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[j]
    return arr


def bucketSort(arr):    
    no_of_buck =  round(math.sqrt(len(arr)))
    bucketArr = [[] for _ in range(no_of_buck)]
    n = len(bucketArr)
    maximumVal = max(arr)

    for i in arr:
        appropriate_bucket = math.ceil(i * n / maximumVal)
        bucketArr[appropriate_bucket-1].append(i)
    
    for i in bucketArr:
        i = insertionSort(i)
    
    arr = []
    for i in bucketArr:
        arr.extend(i)

    print(arr)
```

Insertion Sort itself is an O(n^2) operation and outer loop goes upto sqaure root of the number of elements i.e. O(sqrt(n)), So it should be O(log(n) * n^2)

Comment: sqrt(n) is not O(log(n)). Logarithms grow much more slowly than polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

> Insertion Sort itself is an O(n^2) operation and outer loop goes upto sqaure root of the number of elements i.e. O(sqrt(n)), So it should be O(log(n) * n^2)

You have given an argument why the time complexity might be O(n<sup>2.5</sup>), not O(log(n) * n^2), although there is a relatively simple reason why both of them are not tight upper bounds (loose upper bounds are not wrong, but less interesting, and may be counted as wrong in some contexts).

### The total number of items is still only `n`.

In the worst case, all items are in one bucket, and that's where the O(n²) time complexity comes from. All other distributions of items over buckets are better. The buckets cannot *all* be big, which is what your argument implicitly assumes.

This is an example of why the rule of thumb "multiply the time complexities of nested loops" is just a rule of thumb.